# What does 'the essential straight man for the Socratic sage' mean?

Tags: meaning

Well, ***the Socratic sage*** refers to Holmes while ***the essential straight man*** to inspector Gregory. But what does ***essential straight*** mean?  And what about ***Socratic***?
Thanks in advance.

> The metaphor of barking dogs has been used by historians of religions
> to describe various uses of comparison, but like all good myths, it
> bears retelling in each new context and can always be used in new
> ways. Sherlock Holmes once solved a mystery, the case of Silver Blaze,
> a racehorse, by using a vital clue of omission. When Inspector Gregory
> asked Holmes whether he had noted any point to which he would draw the
> inspector’s attention, Holmes replied, “To the curious incident of the
> dog in the night-time.” “The dog did nothing in the night-time,”
> objected the puzzled inspector, **the essential straight man for the
> Socratic sage**. “That was the curious incident,” remarked Sherlock
> Holmes. The fact that the dog did not bark when someone entered the
> house at night was evidence, in this case evidence that the criminal
> was someone familiar to the dog. Dogs bark at difference — in this
> case, someone different from those with whom the dog was familiar.  We
> cannot hear the sound of one hand clapping; we cannot hear sameness.
> But through the comparative method we can see the blinkers that each
> culture constructs for its retellings of myths. Comparison makes it
> possible for us literally to cross-examine cultures, by using a myth
> from one culture to reveal to us what is not in a telling from another
> culture, to find out the things not “dreamt of in your philosophy” (as
> Hamlet said to Horatio). Moreover, we can use comparative work to test
> theories about our own culture, by noting where our own dogs have not
> barked. Comparison defamiliarizes what we take for granted. We can
> only see the inflection of a particular telling when we see other
> variants.

[The Implied Spider: Politics and Theology in Myth
By Wendy Doniger](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=pn89-ira-rQC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=the%20essential%20straight%20man%20for%20the%20Socratic%20sage.&source=bl&ots=6aAQI5timX&sig=ACfU3U31OUioPa95kPDwCa0d0qRQonjEyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLqOzm1J7qAhXRLqYKHW-pA94Q6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20essential%20straight%20man%20for%20the%20Socratic%20sage.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

The term "straight man" means this:
[American Heritage Dictionary "straight man"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=straight%20man)
"The partner in a comedy team who feeds lines to the other comedian, who then makes witty replies."

The "Socratic sage", Holmes, is a wise man who uses the Socratic method:
[Merriam-Webster "Socratic method"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Socratic%20method)
"the method of inquiry and instruction employed by Socrates especially as represented in the dialogues of Plato and **consisting of a series of questionings the object of which is to elicit a clear and consistent expression of something supposed to be implicitly known by all rational beings**"

So, Holmes is using questions to provoke understanding in the inspector, and providing witty answers to the questions fed to him by his straight man, the inspector.

Definitely a mixed metaphor.

Comment: What a perfect explanation! Thank you, Mr. O'Flaherty.